# Add a WMS singletile layer in Mapbox GL

Tags: openlayers, wms, mapbox

I would like to add a raster wms layer to Mapbox GL but in similar way as [OpenLayers single tiles example](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/single-tile.html)

Mapbox example https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/wms/ use the 256px tile's size declared in code:

```
map.on('load', function () {
map.addSource('wms-test-source', {
'type': 'raster',
// use the tiles option to specify a WMS tile source URL
// https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sources/
'tiles': [
'https://img.nj.gov/imagerywms/Natural2015?bbox={bbox-epsg-3857}&format=image/png&service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetMap&srs=EPSG:3857&transparent=TRUE&width=256&height=256&layers=Natural2015'
],
'tileSize': 256
});
map.addLayer(
{
'id': 'wms-test-layer',
'type': 'raster',
'source': 'wms-test-source',
'paint': {}
},
'aeroway-line'
);
});
```

On the other hand, OpenLayers set the single tile size automatically depending on container's size (full screen in my case):

```
new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
    "Single Tile", 
    "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
    {layers: "basic"}, 
    {singleTile: true, ratio: 1}
)
```

Is possible to make something similar using Mapbox?

Comment: There seem to be no native support for this. This looks like possible solution (never used it): https://gist.github.com/ThomasG77/0feccc76e01bdbfd98b7f628c1c4e6f0

Comment: @TomazicM The behavior is the expected, it could be a solution. I will test it adapting it to my application

Comment: The same code demo, visible in the browser https://gist.githack.com/ThomasG77/0feccc76e01bdbfd98b7f628c1c4e6f0/raw/def838975465efcf45884af95960cad3185c343d/mapbox-gl-js-wms-single-call.html to see the code in action

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find below the same code as in the comment to make only single WMS calls (useful to avoid repeated labels). I've made some refactoring. You should also be aware that you need to consume a WMS server that is able to return single WMS calls (some third party servers have size limitations making them unable to display large WMS images)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Add a WMS Single source</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.11.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@mapbox/sphericalmercator@1.1.0/sphericalmercator.js"></script>
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.11.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    #map {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    function getExtentCoordinatesFromBounds(bounds) {
      return [
        bounds.getNorthWest().toArray(),
        bounds.getNorthEast().toArray(),
        bounds.getSouthEast().toArray(),
        bounds.getSouthWest().toArray()
      ];
    }
    function wmsExtent130FromBounds(bounds) {
      var sm = new SphericalMercator({
        size: 256
      });
      return [
        ...sm.forward(bounds.getSouthWest().toArray()),
        ...sm.forward(bounds.getNorthEast().toArray())
      ];
    }
    function addSingleWms(map, baseUrl) {
      return function() {
        var myCanvas = map.getCanvas();
        var myBounds = map.getBounds();
        var imageCoordinates = getExtentCoordinatesFromBounds(myBounds);
        var imageExtent3857 = wmsExtent130FromBounds(myBounds);
        if (map.getSource(sourceName) && map.getLayer(wmsLayerName)) {
            map.removeLayer(wmsLayerName);
            map.removeSource(sourceName);
        }
        var urlWms = `${baseUrl}?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=topp:states&CRS=EPSG:3857&STYLES=&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:180&WIDTH=${myCanvas.width / window.devicePixelRatio}&HEIGHT=${myCanvas.height / window.devicePixelRatio}&BBOX=${imageExtent3857.join(',')}`;
        map.addSource(sourceName, {
          'type': 'image',
          'url': urlWms,
          'coordinates': imageCoordinates
        });
        map.addLayer({
          'id': wmsLayerName,
          'type': 'raster',
          'source': sourceName,
          'paint': {}
        });
      }
    }
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: {
        "version": 8,
        "sources": {
          "raster-tiles": {
            "type": "raster",
            "tiles": ["a", "b", "c"].map(subdomain => "https://" + subdomain + ".tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"),
            "tileSize": 256
          }
        },
        "layers": [{
          "id": "simple-tiles",
          "type": "raster",
          "source": "raster-tiles",
          "minzoom": 0,
          "maxzoom": 20
        }]
      },
      zoom: 8,
      center: [-74.5447, 40.6892]
    });

    var sourceName = 'wms-test-source';
    var wmsLayerName = 'wms-test-layer';
    var baseUrl = 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wms';
    map.on('load', addSingleWms(map, baseUrl));
    map.on('moveend', addSingleWms(map, baseUrl));
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

The same code demo, visible in the browser https://gist.githack.com/ThomasG77/0feccc76e01bdbfd98b7f628c1c4e6f0/raw/def838975465efcf45884af95960cad3185c343d/mapbox-gl-js-wms-single-call.html to see the code in action.

Comment: I added demo example from comment, so it's all together in one place.